# Source for significant historical events

Tags: game-design, history

I'm designing a game that involves identifying historical events, and I'm looking for an online source that I can use to generate a set of event cards.

For my prototype, I'm using a copy of the game [Chronology](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/834/chronology), but to publish a print-and-play version, I'd need to find or create my own set of cards. If I could find an online source with a permissive licence, that might not be too much work. Other games like Chronology that could be used for prototyping would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best source I've found so far is the [Wikipedia timelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_timelines#History).

Answer (score 3):

I would look at [The Timetables of History](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743270037). Even though they are on low-tech dead trees, the cross-concern linking of people and events is awesome. I have used these books for RPG purposes and general entertainment reading for decades.

I find that the Timetables provide better information (and inspiration!) than the Wikipedia timelines because of the way they connect events, people, and ideas. Especially for game design, the Timetables of History can help you unravel the skeins of history so you know which strings to tug on for desired results.

Comment: I agree, they're great for inspiration, and I've used them to play Blind Dates. Unfortunately, they would be more labour intensive than I was hoping for if I'm just going to web publish this.

Answer (score 2):

It's Amero-centric, but you could use the cards from [Chrononauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Events_on_the_Chrononauts_timeline) as a good starting place.  That link lists everything that happened in real life, but not any of the alternate timeline cards.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. I'm still hoping for something bigger.